# Finding nodes with 2 relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Not sure if the title explains everything but I'm learning Cypher using Neo4j and the Movie Database (from here: https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/) and I'm trying to craft a query that will give me every movie whose director also acted in it.

To give an example of such a movie, Pulp Fiction - Quentin Tarantino both acted in and directed the movie.

I came up with this query for the above example:

```
match (m:Movie)-[:ACTS_IN]-(d:Director)-[:DIRECTED]->(n:Movie)
where d.name STARTS WITH 'Q'
return *
```

But it doesn't seem to work the way I expected it to. I get all the movies he's directed and acted in, whereas I only want the ones where he's done both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already had `d` and `m` declared, so you don't assign labels in the second MATCH statement again. The correct query would look like this

```
MATCH (d:Director)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie) 
WHERE d.name STARTS WITH 'Q'     
MATCH (d)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m) 
RETURN d, collect(m) AS movies
```

Note that based on your initial question, I've modified the return statement as well.

Comment: You can also check to see if the director acted in the movie as part of the predicate. Instead of the second MATCH, you can continue the WHERE clause with the pattern you want to exist: `AND (d)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m)`

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow I just figured it out:

```
match (d:Director)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
match (d:Director)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie)
where d.name STARTS WITH 'Q' 
return *
```

I was honestly expecting to have to use some kind of operator to join the two, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: You could add an extra condition to your `where` clause in the first query, as `and n = m`, but yes, it's simpler to just _use_ the same variable twice.